# Expand details element when URL is called with specific hashes

Tags: javascript, html, hashchange

I have used the `details` and `summary` elements to collapse a section of a page.

```html
<details id="comments">
  <summary>Show comments</summary>
  <ol>
   <li id-"comment-101">This</li>
   <li id-"comment-102">is</li>
   <li id-"comment-103">cool</li>
  </ol>
</details>
```

I have also added this Javascript code to automatically expand the section if the URL is called with the `#comments` hash:

```js
function openTarget() {
  var hash = location.hash.substring(1);
  if(hash) var details = document.getElementById(hash);
  if(details && details.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'details') details.open = true;
}
window.addEventListener('hashchange', openTarget);
openTarget();
```

How can I also expand `details#comments` when the URL is called with any `#comment-X` hash using Javascript (no jQuery)? Ideally the page would also scroll to the point where the element `#comment-X` is present.

Comment: Hmm ... I've somehow missed the details element ... But what comes to the question,  you can select the element with the id in the hash, if the element exists, find the [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) detail element and set its open property to true.

Comment: `if( hash.indexOf('comment') != -1 ) var details = document.getElementById(hash).closest('details');`

Comment: @Banzay thanks! That works in expanding #comments, but the page does not move at the position of the #comment-X element is as I think #comments is not expanded yet when the DOM is loaded..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a question of relaxing your check of the hash to allow more than just exactly "comments", but also "comment-111". I have assumed, as your HTML suggests, that your IDs are numeric.

```
//grab hash and its parts
let hash = location.hash.match(/^#(comment(s|-(\d+)))$/);
if (hash) {

    //resolve to element
    let el = document.getElementById(hash[1]);
    if (el) {

        //open comments - not sure what your .open property does
        el.closest('#comments').open = true;

        //if is hash to specific comment, go to it
        if (hash[3]) location.href = '#'+hash[3];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd assume there are more `details` elements on the page, why not just find the "hashed" element with `getElementById` or  `querySelector`..?